# Is there anything I'm missing in the method I created? I'm confused with method creations

Tags: java, methods

Write a program that converts kilograms to pounds using a method. In the loop, call the method kgTolb(kg) within the loop body. The method header is defined below:

Method headers

```
public static double kgToLb(double kg)
/* returns the converted pounds value where = 2.2 * kg */
```

Create a second method that does the printing of the detail line and implement it in the algorithm above. Here is the method header:

```
public static void print (kg, lb)
/* prints a formatted detail line*/
```

Write a program that converts kilograms to pounds using a method. Implement as we did inn lab9. In the loop, call the method kgTolb(kg) within the loop body.  The method header is defined below.

Method headers

```
public static double kgToLb(double kg)
returns the converted pounds value where lb = 2.2 * kg
```

Sample Execution

```
Enter the beginning value: 1
Conversion Table From KG(s) to LB(s)
Kilograms       Pounds
---------------------
 1              2.2  
 2          4.4
 3          6.6
 4          8.8
 5          11.0
 6          13.2
 7          15.4
 8          17.6
 9          19.8              
10          22.0        
---------------------
End of Program
```

Algorithm

```
Open keyboard for input
Prompt user for beginning value and assign to bVal
Print conversion table headings
eVal = bVal + 9
kg = bVal
while (kg <= eVal)
    lb = kgToLb(kg)
    print kg, lb to terminal //detail line
    kg = kg + 1
Print conversion table footer
Close input
```

Section 3:

Create a second method that does the printing of the detail line and implement in the algorithm above. Here is the method header:

```
public static void print(kg,lb)
prints a formatted detail line as in the sample output
```

Algorithm V2

```
Open keyboard for input
Prompt user for beginning value and assign to bVal
Print conversion table headings
eVal = bVal + 9
kg = bVal
while (kg <= eVal)

    lb = kgToLb(kg)
    print(kg,lb) //detail line
    kg = kg + 1

Print conversion table footer
Close input
```

Section 4:

Create a third method that ensures that the beginning value is greater than zero. Here is the method header:

```
public static boolean isValidBVal(bVal)
returns true if bVal is greater than 0, otherwise false
```

Algorithm V3

```
Open keyboard for input
Prompt user for beginning value and assign to bVal
while (!isValidBVal(bVal)) //makes the method call

    Print “invalid bVal, must be greater than 0.”
    Prompt user for beginning value and assign to bVal

Print conversion table headings
eVal = bVal + 9
kg = bVal
while (kg <= eVal)

    lb = kgToLb(kg)
    print(kg,lb) //detail line
    kg = kg + 1

Print conversion table footer
Close input
```

**My full program**

```
*/import java.util.Scanner;
public class KgTolb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Open keyboard for input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Prompt user for beginning value and assign to bVal
        System.out.println("Enter beginning value ===>   ");
        double bVal = input.nextDouble();

        //Print conversion table headings  
        System.out.println("\n Kilograms\t\t Pounds");
        double eVal = bVal + 9;
        double kg = bVal;
        
        System.out.println("----------------------");
    }
    
    public static double kgToLb(double kg) {
        double lb = kgToLb(kg);
        double kgToLbs = kg * 2.21;
        for(double i = bVal; i <= bVal + 10; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t%.2f\n", i , (i * LB_PER_KG));
            
            kg = kg + 1;
            
            System.out.println("----------------------");
        }
    }
    
    //Close input
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `return` statment at the end of `kgToLb` method, because the method signature shows it is expecting to return a `double`.

Comment: It doesn't seem right (you don't even have the `public static void print` method). Can you add more details of what is expected?

Comment: I updated the question and added the whole program instructions @JoãoDias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there anything missing in the method you created? No, on the contrary, there’s too much in it. You were asked to create *two* methods, `kgToLb()` that converts one kg value and `print()` that prints formatted output. Instead you `kgToLb` method not only converts one kg value, it attempts to convert 11 successive kg values and also does formatted output, which was the job of `print()`.

It seems to me that you are being very loyal to the overall purpose of your program and the expected sample execution. What you are missing is to follow your teacher’s design. Design meaning what goes into which method, including what is supposed to be in the `main` method (“the program”).

From your exercise:

```
public static double kgToLb(double kg)
/* returns the converted pounds value where = 2.2 * kg */
```

So the `kgToLb` method should convert kgs to pounds and return the converted value. Nothing else. It’s a very simple task for a method. What appears to me to be the difficult part for you is to write a method that is correspondingly simple and does not include anything else. It’s really training of abstraction and design more than it’s programming training.

Comment: I'm still having a lot of issues and now I'm getting all sorts of errors 
@Ole V.V.

Comment: Yes, I did notice other problems in your code and chose not to  treat them in my answer. Partly out of laziness, partly because I thought it’s best you fix the basic design problem first and then try to fix the other ones. If you need help with those, I suggest you post a new question. If you do that, please mention it in a comment here and give a link, then I will take a look once I find a good opportunity.